# Paypal Hosted language bug. Based on 'country' instead of 'lc' for Paypal Express button

Tags: paypal, hosted

1. Create a paypal hosted form using the templateD option with lc="GB" but shipping country of another language than English (like NL)
2. When given the option to pay with Paypal Express or credit card, choose the Paypal express option.
3. When redirected to paypal, the paypal login form is shown in dutch because it is using the "country" value instead of the "lc" value. I've confirmed this by forcing "GB" in the country value.

Here's the html form:

```
<form action="https://securepayments.paypal.com/webapps/HostedSoleSolutionApp/webflow/sparta/hostedSoleSolutionProcess" method="post" id="checkout-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="4.13">
    <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0.83">
    <input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="22.98">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="xxx@xxx.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="showShippingAddress" value="true">
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="test">
    <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="test">
    <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="123 Test">
    <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="city" value="Laren">
    <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="1251TM">
    <input type="hidden" name="country" value="NL">
    <input type="hidden" name="state" value="Noord Holland">
    <input type="hidden" name="night_phone_b" value="252525">
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_first_name" value="test">
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_last_name" value="test">
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_address1" value="123 UK Street, Suite UK1">
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_address2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_city" value="Aberdeen">
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_zip" value="AB10">
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_country" value="GB">
    <input type="hidden" name="logoImage" value="https://www.specialistsupplements.com/image/data/specialist-supplements-logo.png">
    <input type="hidden" name="billing_state" value="Aberdeen">
    <input type="hidden" name="showBillingPhone" value="false">
    <input type="hidden" name="showHostedThankyouPage" value="false">
    <input type="hidden" name="buyer_email" value="test@test.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="123">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
    <input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="false">
    <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="xxxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="xxxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="xxxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="123">
    <input type="hidden" name="template" value="templateD">
</form>
```

The "lc" code in this is "GB" which is what should force "English". The problem is a person who does not read dutch may want to send an item to a friend in another country and will not be able to read the payment options. At the very least it should be using the billing_country value, but ultimately use the lc code as that is its intended use.

Answer (score 0):

I found that PayPal was ignoring the `lc` and `billing_country` fields.

In my case, both were set to `CA`, but upon arrival at PayPal, it would always show **United States** for the billing country, not **Canada**.

The workaround I found is to set:

```
<input name="landing_page" value="billing" type="hidden">
```

After I set this variable, PayPal stopped ignoring the `billing_country` field.

Comment: I try your solution by adding this field in my form, but it doesn't work. Only the **lc** field matters. Could you post your entire form ? I tried with this form (https://pastebin.com/nujJit4w) but it failed